# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _toolkit.createSlice) is not a function

Tags: npm, redux-toolkit

I'm in the process of developing an NPM package tailored for React, integrating Redux-Toolkit within its architecture. Prior to its publication, everything functioned seamlessly. However, subsequent to its release, I've encountered the following error.

itemSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const itemSlice = createSlice({
  name: "item",
  initialState: {
    item: 10,
    page: 1,
  },
  reducers: {
    addItemPerPage: (state, actions) => {
      state.item = actions.payload;
      state.page = 1;
    },
    addPage: (state, actions) => {
      state.page = actions.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { addPage, addItemPerPage } = itemSlice.actions;
export default itemSlice.reducer;
```

Store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import itemReducer from "./slices/itemSlice";
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    item: itemReducer,
  },
});
export default store;
```

error

```
itemSlice.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _toolkit.createSlice) is not a function
at ../npm packages/package-name/lib/Redux/slices/itemSlice.js (itemSlice.js:8:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ../npm packages/package-name/lib/components/Component.js (Component.js:11:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ../npm packages/package-name/lib/index.js (index.js:18:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

Comment: Is `@reduxjs/toolkit` correctly installed as a dependency?

Comment: Yes...working fine before publish